# What is the difference between propertyInfo.PropertyType and propertyInfo.GetType?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

It returns different data between `propertyInfo.PropertyType` and `propertyInfo.GetType()`.

I want to know what different it is

```
var propInfo = dataModel.GetProperty("List<string>");

var test1 = propinfo.GetType().IsGenericType; // it returns false;
var test2 = propinfo.PropertyType.IsGenericType; // it returns true;
```

Please give me some idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Read about [Type.GetProperty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperty), what you should pass to this method and the Remarks section of [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype)

Comment: Remove the `IsGenericType` bits - what **then** are the values of `test1` and `test2`?

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for giving me links about GetProperty() and PropertyType. I already checked it before I wrote a question. But It was hard to fully understand, because my poor English skills. I will read it again more carefully. Thank you.

Comment: @mjwills Thank you for comment. test1 returns **Name = "RuntimePropertyInfo" FullName = "System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo"** and test2 returns **Name = "List`1" FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"**

Comment: `GetProperty(String) Searches for the public property with the specified name.`

Comment: `Object` defines the `GetType` method and it's not overridable. **Every** object can have `GetType` called on it and it always does the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `propertyInfo.PropertyType` is the type of the property that the `propertyInfo` object represents. It is `typeof(List<string>)` in your case. On the other hand, `propertyInfo.GetType()` is a type derived from  `typeof(PropertyInfo)`.

Comment: It's not necessarily true that `GetType` will return the same thing as `typeof(PropertyInfo)`. Notably, the first gives you the *runtime type of the object*. This could be something *derived* from `PropertyInfo`, such as [`RuntimePropertyInfo`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/propertyinfo.cs,833669778438826e,references). `PropertyInfo` itself is abstract, in fact, so you're guaranteed that the two aren't equal.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever true, but I think the point that is trying to be made is that the output of `GetType` has absolutely nothing to do with the type of the actual property being referenced.